# Fetch n number of keys from redis

Tags: java, caching, redis

Is there any way I can fetch n number of keys from redis?

I have a huge list of keys in redis , How can I fetch n keys at a time something like fetch 10k record at a time as CSV files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I all depends on redis data types used. For all types you can use **SCAN**, for hashsets **HSCAN** and so on as mentioned here https://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: How do you decide in runtime which keys to retrieve?

Comment: @GuyKorland I need that in alphabetical order. Is there any way I can do it ?

Comment: You might want to consider indexing the data with RediSearch or collecting it with RedisGears

Comment: do you need the values of those keys as well?

Comment: @YaronSchwimmer No just the keys

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is using the [`scan`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command. It allows you iterate over the keys by returning a cursor you can use for the next query.

For example `scan 0 count 10000` to get the first 10k keys, and then use the cursor in the response for the next iteration `scan <cursor> count 10000`.

If you need the keys sorted then I'm not sure there's an easy solution, but you can try and force it with the `match` option of `scan`. For example to get all the first 10k keys that start with 'a': `scan 0 count 10000 match a*`.